# How to make symfony Controller variable a global?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony-3.4

```
public indexFunction(){
  $var = 'Apple';
  //set $var global
}
```

So that `$var` can be accessed in base template.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to the Symfony.. I saw in Documentation but I din't get it.. ;(

Comment: If you want access variable anywhere(or save you variable between requests) you need use storage like redis, memcached etc. Also you can use sessions.

Comment: Sorry I have read the questions to quickly, so indeed must must use Twig globals as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you want it as static value just put it in the config file:

```
    # app/config/config.yml

     twig:
         globals:
         var: 'Apple'
```

if you want it as dynamic variable you can give the twig the service id:

```
twig:
globals:
    # the value is the service's id
    var: '@AppBundle\Service\yourData'
```

Comment: Displaying {{ var }} is showing error like "Cannot convert to string"

Comment: because the variable you are passing is an array and you can access the data inside it like an array try to dump the variable to see how to access the values inside it  {{ var.var.your value key }}

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the variable to the template:

```
// AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
public indexFunction()
{
    $var = 'Apple';

    return $this->render('index.html.twig', array(
        'var' => $var,
    ));
}
```

If you really want to have a global variable available to all of your templates you should set it in your twig config:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        var: 'value'
```

after that you can write out the value of the variable in the twig template with `{{ var }}`

EDIT:

Or finally example using session - saving the variable into the session

```
// AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
public indexFunction()
{
    $var = 'Apple';
    $session = $this->get('session');        
    $session->set('var', $var);
    ...
}
```

after that you can retrieve it in the twig template like this

```
{# /app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}
{{ app.session.get('var') }}
```

Comment: I know the both.. i mean to say how to make $var global.. So that the 'Apple' is printed anywhere...

Comment: What do you want to use this for? What is anywhere? In any action defined in the controller or in any twig template?

Comment: I have added example using PHP session as suggested by @PizzaLover

Comment: @PrananSubba I think this is what you're looking for
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html

Use the yaml config for static values or the service version for dynamic values.

Comment: The original question is about Twig global, providing an exemple with session is more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Dynamic:**

In the bundle path (Example: **src/AppBundle**) add a file called "**YourNameTwigExtension.php**". This file will be a class (**YourNameTwigExtension**) that extends "**\Twig_Extension**" class and implements the interface "**\Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface**". Inside the "**YourNameTwigExtension**" class implement the **getGlobals**() method. Example:

```
//....
class YourNameTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension implements \Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface {
    //...

    public function getGlobals() {
        $data = array();

        $data['user'] = $this->session->get('user');
        $data['menu'] = $this->session->get('menu');
        $data['actions'] = $this->session->get('actions');
        $data['view'] = $this->session->get('view');

        return $data;
    }
}
```

> In TWIG you will use: {{ user }}, {{ menu }}, {{ actions }}, etc...

**Warning**: Add in **app/config/services.yml**:

```
 twig.extension.yourname_twig_extension:
        class: YourBundle\YourNameTwigExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

**Static:**

If you need to use the static variables, in **app/config/parameters.yml**:

```
twig:
    globals:
        portal_name: 'Portal'
        portal_img_logo: logo.png
        portal_favicon: favicon.ico
        logowidth: 350px
```

Symfony Doc: [How to Inject Variables into all Templates (i.e. global Variables)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html)

Sorry my English.. **Good Work**!

Comment: On symfony 4 you need to implement `Twig\Extension\GlobalsInterface` instead of `Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface`